# How to check if my container fully load is completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue, do not know if it possible or not, how to check if my container is already loaded or not, because sometimes it is being loaded faster, sometimes slower and if it does not succeed in time getting an error in javaScript where gridview some functions are not recognizable(because the gridview is not loaded fast enough). Hope it is clear. Thanks for Your time.

Code:

```
function LoadPartial(partialUrl, container) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: partialUrl,
        success: function (returnData) {
            $(container).html(returnData);
        }
    });
    //.done(function () {
    //    return;
    //});
}
```

Comment: You can put your functionality in the `success`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this.

```
$(".container").load(function (){
         alert("Loaded :)");
});
```

Let me know in-case this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
if ($('#mycontainer').data('loaded')) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to find event when data received use "complete" function:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: partialUrl,
  success: function (returnData) {
    $(container).html(returnData);
  },
  complete: function() {
    console.log('container filled with data');
  }
});
```